# How do I force a custom error in grunt if command line argument is not specified?

Tags: gruntjs

I have the following option in grunt:

```
host: grunt.option('myoption')
```

However if the user does not specifiy one I do not want any of my task to work.  How do I check for this in the beginning?

Comment: http://gruntjs.com/api/grunt.fail

Answer (score 0):

Using custom tasks, you can check that specific conditions are met prior to running your build workflow.  The example below checks if the option is defined, and fails if not present:

```
function preFlightCheck() {
    if (!grunt.option('myoption')) {
        grunt.fail.fatal('myoption not set!');
    }
}

grunt.registerTask('preFlightCheck', preFlightCheck);
```

Once you've created the custom task, prepend it to your workflow:

```
grunt.registerTask('default', ['preFlightCheck', 'jslint', 'less']);
```

One thing to keep in mind with this approach: if the workflow is invoked with the `--force` flag, grunt will continue to execute the tasks, even if `preFlightCheck` fails.  Alternatively, you can use `preFlightCheck` to set the value of `grunt.option('myoption')` if it's missing:

```
function preFlightCheck() {
    if (!grunt.option('myoption')) {
        grunt.log.warn('myoption not provided, defaulting to fooBar');
        grunt.option('myoption', 'foobar');
    }
}
```